# What might trigger a CI sessions duplicate ID?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I am running Codeigniter 4 and using a database for my sesssions. For some reason, my users (on production) are getting the following errors:

`ERROR - 2023-02-25 15:19:48 --> mysqli_sql_exception: Duplicate entry 'ci_session:XXXXX' for key 'sessions.PRIMARY' in /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php:29 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Database/MySQLi/Connection.php(292): mysqli->query() #1 /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Database/BaseConnection.php(666): CodeIgniter\Database\MySQLi\Connection->execute() #2 /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Database/BaseConnection.php(593): CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection->simpleQuery() #3 /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Database/BaseBuilder.php(1916): CodeIgniter\Database\BaseConnection->query() #4 /var/www/html/system_4_2_11/Session/Handlers/DatabaseHandler.php(199): CodeIgniter\Database\BaseBuilder->insert() #5 [internal function]: CodeIgniter\Session\Handlers\DatabaseHandler->write() #6 [internal function]: session_write_close() #7 {main}`

Noting that my code isn't actually playing any part - this is the complete chain.

Here is my sessions table:

`CREATE TABLE` sessions`(`id`varchar(60) NOT NULL,`ip_address`varchar(200) NOT NULL,`timestamp`int unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',`data `blob NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY` ci_sessions_timestamp `(`timestamp`) ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1`

I had wondered if it could be the user is trying to login on a new tab but I've tried to trigger it and don't get a problem. Does anyone know what might be triggering this error? (Apart from the obvious fact the ID is unique and its trying to be re-entered!)

Could it be an IP address change? The platform is used on a mobile network so wondering if it would change often enough to cause a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed it is an IP address change. I was able to simulate it with a VPN I've recently setup and basically this error is thrown when the IP address changes. The end user experience is they're logged out but this error is thrown in the background.

My solution will be turn matching IP address off in the config as this has happened a few times!